# node js - как можно преобразовать функцию в json и обратно?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Общество, прошу подсказать как правильно это можно реализовать.
У меня есть одно решение через `eval`, но это как-то не по фэншую.

```
// код
var inbox={};
inbox.fn='date=date*2; console.log(date);';
var func=function(date){eval(inbox.fn.toString());};
// вызов функции
func(9);
```

Попробовал что-то подобное:

```
var inbox={};
inbox.fn={"test":function(data){data=data*2; return console.log(data)}};
// вызов функции
inbox.fn.test(34);

var src=inbox.fn.test.toString();
console.log(src);
```

Вижу такое:

```
68
function (data){data=data*2; return console.log(data)}
```

Как обратно из этого:

> "function (data){data=data*2; return console.log(data)}"

Создать объект функцию?

Comment: Не использовать toString()

Comment: суть проблемы: необходимо взять функцию из формата json - преобразовать в рабочий объект, выполнить и удалить. Как проще это реализовать пока не могу понять, тут просто пардон мои "потуги"...

Comment: Если код функции в строке, то только `eval`, подумайте о том, что код передавать и выполнять в таком виде не очень хорошо.

Comment: Такой трюк не пройдет, у `json` нет типа `function`. И где именно Вы это хотите сделать? Если на сервере, то нативного точно ничего нет, но возможно если поискать в гугле по тегу serialization что и найдется. А вот если на клиенте, то там все просто, там ведь тег `<script>` из текста сделает выполняемый код.

Comment: необходима реализация на стороне сервера в nodejs, для клиента уже есть решение и оно сильно отличается от серверного... :-)

Comment: Кажется нашел решение, постараюсь завтра выложить пример. Информация [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/scope-new-function) и кстати, я могу ошибаться, но мне говорили, что эту тему обсуждали где то на лекциях от Яндекса...

Comment: @Valery, по сути тот же `eval`

Comment: есть еще такая альтернатива eval: `my_function = new Function('текст функции')`

Comment: Если нужен именно JSON то почему бы строку не прогнать через JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tело функции храню в формате **text**, когда необходимо выполнить код
создаю новый объект **function**, и присваиваю ему тело **text**.
В таком варианте удобно хранить функции в базе и использовать по мере необходимости. Объект после использования удаляется...
Затея состояла в том, чтобы гарантированно тело функции было проверенным перед использованием. То есть присутствует возможность криптования и.т.д.
Спасибо за подсказки всем огромное. Если есть альтернатива, буду рад узнать. :-)

```
    var data='var a=1,b=2; return console.log(a+b)';
    var LibFn={"Fn0":{}};
    LibFn.Fn0=new Function(data);
    LibFn.Fn0();
    LibFn.Fn0=null;
```